# Можно ли сказать "чему-то недовольных"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, местоимения

Предложение звучит так:"В детстве мне едва ли удавалось рассмотреть его сквозь огромную толпу, вечно чему-то недовольных людей."
Понятное дело, что "чем-то недовольных" звучит привычней. Но если мы имеем дело с художественным текстом, есть ли правило, запрещающее использовать "чему-то" вместо "чем-то"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я поняла, это современное произведение в жанре "фанфик" https://ficbook.net/readfic/12415374

https://ficbook.net/readfic/12415374/31924570

**Фанфик** — произведение, созданное поклонником книги по ее мотивам с участием главных или второстепенных действующих лиц и использованием фабулы или отдельных эпизодов произведения.

**Текст стилизованный, современный**, ошибок в нем достаточно. Даже в словаре Даля указано только управление Т.п. Можно предположить **неверное употребление падежа** по аналогии: **рад чему, доволен чем**, так как в современном словаре указана **одна форма**:

**НЕДОВОЛЬНЫЙ,**  Испытывающий недовольство, неудовлетворение **кем-, чем-л.** Н-ая толпа. Недовольна собой, своей внешностью, выступлением. Чем ты недоволен? [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=недовольный&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

*Я всегда восхищался капитаном, с самого детства, как только до моих любопытных ушей дошло имя Леви Аккерман. Я возвел его в степень святых, недосягаемых людей, сделал его для себя предметом искусства, кумиром, экспонатом на который можно только смотреть и восхищаться – ни больше, ни меньше.

В детстве мне едва ли удавалось рассмотреть его сквозь огромную толпу, **вечно чему-то недовольных людей**. Я мог видеть лишь его темноволосую макушку и часть зеленого плаща...*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138778/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).